# Using maven-shade-plugin with maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

I have a project which packages several (executable jar) assemblies using the maven-assembly-plugin - basically the same code but with different sets of data for different clients.

I have a need to use spring in my executable jar and due to the file naming in spring I need to move to using the maven-shade-plugin for jar creation.  This works fine and I can create the executable jar but I cannot work out how to assemble my other files into this new shaded jar because the shade plugin does not offer many of the feature available from the assembly plugin.

The shade plugin executes before the assembly one so I'm assuming I could somehow use the shaded artifact in my assembly but all my attempts so far have failed.  Is it possible to create an assembly that takes the existing shaded jar and simply injects binaries and some other files into it?

Answer (score 4):

Setting shadedArtifactAttached to true will cause maven to attach the shaded artifact to the project instead of the original artifact.  This should resolve your problem.

```
<shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
```